# Python - Joining multiple 2D arrays into one 3D array

Tags: python, arrays

So I have multiple files that can be accessed and be treated as 2D arrays.
What I would like to do is take all those 2D arrays and put them in a single 3D array.
For example, if I have 10 files with the shapes (100,100), when I combine them, I should be left with a 3D array of shape (10,100,100). The following attempt I have is the following:

```
filenames = glob.glob('source')
preset = np.empty([100,100], dtype = 'int16')
for file in filenames:
    data = fits.open(file)[0].data
    np.vstack([preset,data]).reshape((10,100,100))
```

But what I'm getting is the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 20000 into shape (10,100,100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing the operation pair by pair. Try to perform this on all the arrays together:

```
arrs = [fits.open(file)[0].data for file in filenames]
np.vstack(arrs).reshape((10,100,100))
```

Or even more direct:

```
np.stack(arrs)
```